# Class constructor including parameter of that exact same class

Tags: java, constructor

Just recently I looket at the source code of the java.lang.String class (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) and I noticed that the constructor used (or at least one specific constructor) relies on a parameter of type String. How is that possible? Assuming following code

`String s = new String("String!");`

How does the compiler do this? Inside the parenthesis there is passed a string object, right? But this needs to be somehow instantiated (by the compiler I guess?) as well? Or how does that work?

I on purpose used the instantiation of a String object instead of a string literal since string literals are allocated differently on a memory pool instead of string objects (heap).

All the best, David

Comment: write `string s = new string(){"String!"}`
you initialize class same way.

Comment: @MasoudHosseini There are many errors in your short code example ...

Comment: @Tom yes, right, i confused with c#
Mr David Becher you should use from this link.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_strings.htm

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class has multiple constructors. The instance being passed in can be created using a different constructor:

```
String string = new String();
new String(string);
```

You don't need to understand how string literals create/reuse objects to understand how `String` can have the constructor `String(String)`

Answer (score 0):

The java compiler will compile much and afterwards do some checks. This is possible as a class is like a .obj or .o, containing *names* later on "linked".

In the case mentioned that in fact poses no challenge to the compilation, or run-time use. Also for non-standard classes: one could alway pas `null`.

There are more uglier things to be seen:

```
public interface IFC {
    public static final IFC SOME_CONSTANT = new IMPL();
}

public class IMPL implements IFC {
}
```

About that example. The constructor `String(String)` stems from the beginning of Java. In C++ one would call it a *copy constructor*. As String is immutable, it servers no purpose: `s.equals(new String(s))` so it is really **bad style**. (Maybe it was added for disabling `==`.)

Answer (score 0):

> How does the compiler do this? Inside the parenthesis there is passed a string object, right?

Not really. If you look at the API for String constructors, it actually receive the argument as `char array`.

> `String str = "abc";`
>    is equivalent to:
>
> `char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`
>
> `String str = new String(data);`

Answer (score 0):

That's what the compiler does under the hood.
The compiler could e.g. convert the string literal (`"abc"`) to a character array and use the ctor which accepts the `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a program like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s = new String("String!");
       System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

When compiled, you'll get a .class file containing the bytecode for this program. You can view the bytecode by invoking `javap -c -v -l -s Test.class` (`javap` is part of the JDK), and it'll print out something like this:

```
Classfile /C:/Test.class
  Last modified 08.03.2015; size 454 bytes
  MD5 checksum 0649bf262c557480c276e268762a1dd5
  Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #8.#17         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #18            // java/lang/String
   #3 = String             #19            // String!
   #4 = Methodref          #2.#20         // java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #5 = Fieldref           #21.#22        // java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   #6 = Methodref          #23.#24        // java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   #7 = Class              #25            // Test
   #8 = Class              #26            // java/lang/Object
   #9 = Utf8               <init>
  #10 = Utf8               ()V
  #11 = Utf8               Code
  #12 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #13 = Utf8               main
  #14 = Utf8               ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #15 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #16 = Utf8               Test.java
  #17 = NameAndType        #9:#10         // "<init>":()V
  #18 = Utf8               java/lang/String
  #19 = Utf8               String!
  #20 = NameAndType        #9:#27         // "<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #21 = Class              #28            // java/lang/System
  #22 = NameAndType        #29:#30        // out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #23 = Class              #31            // java/io/PrintStream
  #24 = NameAndType        #32:#27        // println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #25 = Utf8               Test
  #26 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #27 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  #28 = Utf8               java/lang/System
  #29 = Utf8               out
  #30 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  #31 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
  #32 = Utf8               println
{
  public Test();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 1: 0

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=2, args_size=1
         0: new           #2                  // class java/lang/String
         3: dup
         4: ldc           #3                  // String String!
         6: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         9: astore_1
        10: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        13: aload_1
        14: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        17: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 3: 0
        line 4: 10
        line 5: 17
}
SourceFile: "Test.java"
```

While this looks very confusing (and I am not very deep into bytecode), **I'll try to cut it down to this**:

The Constant Pool is the part of the class file containing "fixed" Information like method signatures or texts (yes: String texts). The code section contains the actual code that should be executed, and it uses references to the Constant Pool.

So, how is the text `"String!"` actually loaded? In the code block on `ldc #3` the value with index `#3` is loaded and put on the stack. `#3` is the reference to `#19` which is the actual text `String!`.

The next bytecode instruction then does an `invokespecial` using index `#4` which is the `String` constructor with another `String` as parameter - a "copy constructor" as described in other answers (`<init>` refers to the constructor, and the other part is the parameter type and return type).

While this might sum up at least part of what happens, **one detail still remains somehow unclear**: how does the runtime convert the literal text `String!` from `#19` into a *`String` object*?

After playing around with some similar codes and their bytecode representations I can only make an educated guess: the runtime has hardcoded support for converting string literals into `String` objects (e.g. in a similar way the code `long c = 42L;` gets splitted into `#2 = Long 42l` and `ldc2_w #2`, you can test that by modifying the example, and then compile and decompile it).

*Further links:*

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings
- JBE, a Java Bytecode Editor (GUI) http://set.ee/jbe/